# Batch variable not put in for in loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I want to get a variable from a file, then use it into a for loop.

Here is my script:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set host=myIp
set user=myUser
set password=passwd
set database=myDb

set /p from=<tmp.txt
echo !from!
FOR /f "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a IN ('sqlcmd -S MY-SRV\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[MyTable] WHERE Time > !from!" -h -1') DO (
    set "ii=%%e"
    set ii=!ii:,=.!
    set "insert=(%%c, '%%d', '!ii!')"
    if "!sqlv!" == "" (set "sqlv=!insert!") else (set "sqlv=!sqlv!, !insert!")
)
echo %sqlv%
REM mysql -h !host! -u !user! --password=!password! -D !database! -e "INSERT INTO MyTable(A, B, C) VALUES !sqlv!"
```

Here is the **minimal code**:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p from=<tmp.txt
echo !from!
FOR /f "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a IN ('sqlcmd -S MY-SRV\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[MyTable] WHERE Time > !from!" -h -1') DO (
    
)
```

But, the `!from!` variable is not put into the `FOR /f` part. The sql query return issue as there is missing part.

The variable is will set as the `echo !from!` print the right value.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably you need to escape the `>` in the sql command as `cmd` will interpret it as a redirector. Use `^>` instead of `>` - `^` is used to "escape" (turn off the special meaning of)  the `>`. Also, there is no need to use `delayedexpansion` in this code. `!var!` is used to extract the run-time value within a code block (parenthesised series of commands). `%var%` will do perfectly well hers.

Comment: @Magoo if you want to check, I added the other part of my code (it were a minimal MRE). I think I have to use DelayedExpension in the "DO" part, that's why I keep it yet

Comment: Fair enough. The only `code block` is the `do` part of the `for` loop. Within this loop, `ii` and `sqlv` are changed, so you need `!var!` to access the modified values. `from` is not changed, so you can use `%var%`. It's academic really - just that `!var!` is **required** for accessing values that are **changing within a code block**, hence `!var!` implies "This value changes in the loop" whereas `%var%` will not change. The code should work as you have posted it - If you change the `>` to `^>`. Try observing that line with `echo on`.

Comment: ...and IMHO, `if "!sqlv!" == "" (set "sqlv=!insert!") else (set "sqlv=!sqlv!, !insert!") is better written as `if defined sqlv (set "sqlv=!sqlv!, !insert!") else (set "sqlv=!insert!")` or even simply `set "sqlv=!sqlv!, !insert!"` and then outside the loop `set sqlv=%sqlv:~2%` to remove the leading `, `

`

Comment: @Magoo I don't understand why it could be better as there is one more action. Else, with `%from%` (and by fixing another typo) it works fine thanks :)